# Mapping carbon sequestration potential as green infrastructure function?

Tags: data, geology, references, environmental-monitoring

I have a small project where I have to do mapping of potential areas for carbon sequestration in the Adelaide Metropolitan area in South Australia. I have no idea what data do I need.

So far looking at literature I understand I can do it through NDVI but have no further idea.

My project is simple, just showing the potential carbon storage area only, not to calculate C02.

Can anyone help me in finding methodology or relevant literature.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [i-Tree Vue](https://www.itreetools.org/vue/index.php) to do this in the past, free to use just need the following NLCD datasets for your study area:

> - 29 Land Cover classifications
> - Percent Impervious Cover
> - Percent Tree Canopy
>
> i-Tree Vue allows you to make use of the freely available National
>   Land Cover Database (NLCD) satellite-based imagery to assess your
>   community's land cover, including tree canopy, and some of the
>   ecosystem services provided by your current urban forest. The effects
>   of planting scenarios on future benefits can also be modeled.
>
> i-Tree Vue allows everyday users to easily utilize the imagery
>   datasets and quickly assess their region's broad characteristics over
>   these three areas.
>
> In addition, i-Tree Vue will allow users to model basic scenarios
>   producing simple analyses outputs including:
>
> - Carbon Storage
> - Carbon Sequestration
> - Pollution Removal
> - Tree Canopy grow-out modeling